# 403 Forbidden Error after copy a project in htdocs

Tags: 14.04, lamp, xampp, htdocs

I successfully installed xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-4 in my ubuntu 14.04. The XAMPP is installed in `/opt/lampp`.
I get an 403 Forbidden Error message after I copied a HTML project in **htdocs** Folder.

What I did and tried:

1. I copied the project by `gksudo nautilus /opt/lampp/htdocs`
2. I tried to change the ownership of the /opt/lampp/htdocs/ to me.
3. I changed the folder's permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**About the error**

The 403 Forbidden Error means that the web server (httpd daemon) cannot access the public documents (the web pages) that need to be served.

**Possible results of what you did:**

1. All actions in 1 done by the root user resulting all files owned by root so the httpd daemon cannot access them.
2. You now have the ownership of `/opt/lampp/htdocs/` and this has the same results as number 1 above.
3. You did not mentioned how the permissions are set now thus it is unclear what is accessible right now.

**Possible solution:**

In my server, I host all public documents at `/srv/www/` but the solution will be the same.

Give the ownership to the httpd daemon (Apache, Nginx, etc), that is:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /opt/lampp/htdocs/
```

Assuming that the httpd daemon is named **www-data** and belongs to the **www-data** group, else you will have to adapt it accordingly.

In general when setting a web server you want the server user to be the owner of what will be served. **Note** this is **not** the case with languages such like Python where say a Django based project must not live inside the public directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set your permissions and created your virtual hosts files but still get the error look to your apache config.

The apache2 configuration file now has a default security model that may be preventing your directory being served. I host mine in my home directory which I always have to add to this part of the configuration to apache2.conf.

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Around line 146 you will see the following section.

```
# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

Add your custom web directory to this section. Tweak the other parameters as needed.

```
<Directory /home/my_custom_directory/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Note: I use drupal which needs the AllowOveride All for the .htaccess file to work. You may not need this in your final config.